# seg-faulting when trying to enqueue in priority queue in C

Tags: c

```
void enQ(int* q, int value){
    if(q[0] == -1){
        q[0] = value;
        q[1] = -1;
        return;
    }
    int found = 0;
    int last_index; 
    int count = 0;
    while(q[count] != -1){
        count++;
    }
    last_index = count;
    int i = 0;
    while(q[i] != -1){
        if(q[i] < value){
            int j = last_index;
            while(j != i){
                q[j+1]=q[j];
                j--;
            }
            q[i]=value;
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found == 0){
        q[last_index] = value;
        q[last_index+1] = -1;
}
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int* q;
    q[0] = -1; // initialize queue by making first element of new queue -1...
    enQ(q,1);
}
```

I made a simple priority queue in C.  The problem is that when I call enQ on an int*, the program segfaults.  I have no idea why.  How do I fix the segfault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an uninitialized pointer, meaning it will point to a random location. Either declare `q` as an array, e.g.

```
int q[10];
```

Or dynamically allocate memory for it:

```
int *q = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

Both of these create space for ten values (index `0` to `9`).

Also in the last case, where you dynamically allocate the memory, you have to remember to `free` the memory when you're done with it.

---

You might also want to keep track of the size, so you don't queue to many items.

Comment: So, I replaced the int* q with  int *q = malloc(sizeof(int) * 128);, but when I call enQ and add ONE item it segfaults again.  I really don't get why it's still doing it.